# Dealing with probability density functions

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X$, $Y$ be independent random variables with the common pdf
>    \begin{eqnarray*} f(u) &=& \left\{\begin{array}{ll} u\over2 &
>  \mbox{for } 0 < u < 2\\ 0 &\mbox{elsewhere} \end{array}\right.\\
> \end{eqnarray*}
>   Set up an explicit double integral for $P(X Y > 1)$
>
> Let $Z$ be the maximum of $X,Y$ (That is, $Z = X$ if $X \geqslant Y$, and $Z= Y$ 
>    if $Y > X$). Find $P(Z\leqslant 1)$
>
> Find the pdf $g(z)$ of $Z$, being sure to define $g(z)$ for all
>    numbers $z$.

This is a problem on a practice exam I'm studying, but I really have no idea how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sketch the plane with coordinate axes and draw on it the square region (of  area $4$) over which the joint density is nonzero.  Determine the joint density
  function $f_{X,Y}(u,v) = f_X(u)f_Y(v)$.
- Sketch the hyperbola $xy=1$ in the first quadrant and persuade yourself 
  $P\{XY > 1\}$  is the total probability mass in one of the two regions into which the hyperbola divides the square.
- Find $P\{XY>1\}$ by integrating $f_{X,Y}(u,v)$ over the region you just
  identified.

---

$F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\} = P\{X \leq z, Y \leq z\} = P\{X \leq z\}P\{Y \leq z\}$.